# Output commit information and filenames

Tags: git

I'd like to print filenames, date, and authors related to my last N commits on the repository.

The following are my tries.

```
git log -n 5 --pretty="Author: %cn %n Data: %ad %n"
```

to show data and author of the last 5 commits but the list of file is missing.

```
git ls-files | while read file; do git log -n 1 --pretty="$file
%n Author: %cn %n Date: %ad %n" -- $file; done
```

to show also the filenames but, in this case, I see the last five commits for each file and this is not what I want.

How can I output the list of files and information related to the latest commits with an output like the following?

```
file1
file2
Author: <name1>
Date: <date1>

file3
file4
Author: <name2>
Date: <date2>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "information about filenames"? Remember, a commit is a project snapshot, so every commit contains *all* files in the project at the time when the commit was made. Is that what you want to show?

Comment: You're right, it was not clear. I edited the question

Comment: Do they files have to come before the author and date? Printing them after author/date is trivial (`--name-only`). Inverting their order is a bit more involved …

Comment: As knittl suggested, it worked but with filenames at the end and also with no possibility to format the output in the same way of the pretty string. Btw thanks for the reply, it helped.

Comment: @Alez so you definitely want the files to come before the author and date?

Comment: Primarily I'd like a way to format the filenames, like the pretty does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
$ git log -n 5 --name-only --pretty="format:Author: %cn %nDate: %ad"
```

which will give an output like:

```
Author: <name>
Date: <date>
file1
file2
...
```

Comment: should have reloaded the page to see that you've already perfectly answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `--name-only` to your command like:

```bash
git log -n 5 --pretty="format:Author: %cn %nDate: %ad" --name-only
```

if you instead of `name-only` add `name-status`, you additionally get the status of the files.

```bash
Author: <name>
Date: <date>
A   file1
M   file2
D   file3
...
```

with

- Added (A)
- Copied (C)
- Deleted (D)
- Modified (M)
- Renamed (R)
- Changed (T)
- Unmerged (U)
- Unknown (X)
- Pairing Broken (B)